How to Automatically Apply Section Headings to Slides in Quarto Reveal.js Presentations?
I’m working on a Quarto presentation using Reveal.js, and I’m trying to automate the process of applying section headings to all slides within a section. Specifically, I want each slide under a particular section heading (e.g., ## animal) to automatically display that heading, without manually repeating it on each slide.
Here’s a simplified version of my Quarto presentation file:
---
title: "Dummy title"
format: revealjs
slide-level: 2
---

## animal

- slide 1

---

- slide 2

---

- slide 3

## fruits

- slide 4

---

- slide 5


Desired Behavior:
All slides under ## animal should display "animal" as a heading. 
All slides under ## fruits should display "fruits" as a heading. 
I want this to be done dynamically without manually inserting the section heading into each slide.
I’ve been unable to find a straightforward method to automatically apply the section heading to each slide within that section in Quarto. Is there a built-in way in Quarto or Reveal.js to achieve this, or is there a recommended workaround that could simplify this process?

I have created an Quarto filter extension reveal-autoheader in response to this question. Usage is simple. Install the filter in your presentation directory and use the filter.
---
title: "Dummy title"
format: revealjs
slide-level: 2
filters:
  - reveal-autoheader
---

## Animal

- slide 1

---

- slide 2

---

- slide 3

## Fruits

- slide 4

---

- slide 5



